# How do I get randomly generated userID from .push() in Firebase

Tags: java, firebase

Currently I am adding my user class to a firebase database using this code:

```
public void onClick(View v)
        {

            Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://xxxxxx.firebaseio.com/");

            createAccount(emailString, passwordString);

            User user = new User ();
            user.setEmail(emailString);
            user.setPassword(passwordString);

            ref.child("users").push().setValue(user);



        }
```

Right now, since I use the .push() method, I am creating a unique ID in my database. How do I pull that unique ID? I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16637035/in-firebase-when-using-push-how-do-i-pull-the-unique-id) tutorial but I don't understand how to implement it.

Comment: I think you are trying to combine android with javascript. check out docs :  https://firebase.google.com/docs/

Comment: Hmm. I think you're right. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DatabaseReference dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(); //get the reference to your database
User user = new User ();
user.setEmail(emailString);
user.setPassword(passwordString);
String yourKey = dbRef.child("users").push().getKey(); //get the key
dbRef.child("users").child(yourKey).setValue(user); //insert user in that node
```

But if you want to access that node (yourKey) later, you will need to store it in some sort of permanent storage like a database on your web server.

Comment: This did exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Great example of how to get key check these docs out helped me a lot.
[Firebase Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write)

```
// Get a key for a new Post. 

var newPostKey = firebase.database().ref().child('posts').push().key;
```