# firebase: get key of ThenableReference

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working with Firebase and Javascript. I need to get the key to a reference that was created by `push()`.

My code waits on the promise returned by push and then reads the key. It looks like this:

```
firebase.database().ref("preds/").push()
.then(function(newReference){
    console.log(newReference.key);
});
```

Now I'm looking at a section of code written by a colleague. It doesn't use promises. Instead, it makes direct use of the key:

```
var newReference = firebase.database().ref("preds/").push()
console.log(newReference.key)
```

This does look much nicer (especially since the real code is longer than these examples). But I suspect that it might be a race condition. What if we're still waiting for a response from the database and the key is already used ?
But I was not able to produce problems with his code.

I looked at the Firebase [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.ThenableReference), and they are a bit confusing.
It says that `push()` returns a:

> Combined Promise and Reference; resolves when write is complete, but can be used immediately as the Reference to the child location.

Their example looks like this:

> ```
> var messageListRef = firebase.database().ref('message_list');
> var newMessageRef = messageListRef.push();
> newMessageRef.set({
>   'user_id': 'ada',
>   'text': 'The Analytical Engine weaves algebraical patterns just as the Jacquard loom weaves flowers and leaves.'
> });
> ```

This looks similar to the use of `newReference.key`, but none of it is blocking. If I understand correctly, these functions are just chained up for asynchronous execution.
However, they do say that the reference can be used immediately to access the `child location`.

I searched SO and found this question: [In Firebase when using push() How do I pull the unique ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16637035/in-firebase-when-using-push-how-do-i-pull-the-unique-id)
Dan_Mindru says:

> To anybody finding this question & using Firebase 3+, the way you get
>   auto generated object unique ids after push is by using the key
>   property (not method) on the promise snapshot

And his code looks just like my initial version:

```
firebase
  .ref('item')
  .push({...})
  .then((snap) => {
     const key = snap.key 
  })
```

I know this is a very common question around firebase, but I hope I have supplied enough context to justify my confusion.
What is the proper way to get the key of a newly created reference ?
Do I have to wait for the promise or can I directly access the key ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key that is generated when you call `push()` is a pure client-side operation. No call to the server is involved when you call `push()` without arguments. So the first two snippets of code you shared are equivalent.

In your last code snippet the `push({...})` *does* call out to the server to write the object to the database. But here too the key for the new child node is generated in the client-side code.

For more on these push IDs, see the blog post: [The 2^120 Ways to Ensure Unique Identifiers](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/02/the-2120-ways-to-ensure-unique_68.html).

Comment: That's great, thanks. (I thought the key might require communication with the server. Not necessarily to avoid clashes, I know they are very unlikely. But to ensure a proper ordering. The keys are created from a timestamp and ordered by time. So without some sync this invariant of order in time might be broken. But maybe they don't make hard assumptions about it)

Comment: When the client establishes its initial connection, it determines its offset to the server's time. This is used on calculating the push IDs. The offset is also exposed on `.info/serverTimeOffset`: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/offline-capabilities#clock-skew.